# No Internet on Clients while in Domain

Tags: windows-server-2016

I want to create a little network with server and some clients. So far I installed Windows Server 2016, installed DNS and an Active Directory on my server. No DHCP on server, the router will do the job.

The server has a static IP, standard gateway pointing to the router IP and DNS pointing to the server itself.

Client has a static IP, standard gateway pointing to the router and DNS pointing to the server. Client and server can ping each other (allowed icmp in firewalls) and client is in my created domain.

Currently I can't search something on the internet from my client. When I change the DNS on my client from server to router internet is available but then I'm not in my domain anymore or?

I did some research but can't try it now. I read that an alternative dns server on my clients could do the trick like 8.8.8.8 or pointing to the router. Another thing I read is to set the DNSforwarding on my server to e.g. 8.8.8.8 or pointing to the router.

Does anyone has an idea why I have no connection to the internet or could share some thoughts on my research?

Answer (score 4):

Clients should use internal DNS. If they don't they would be unable to resolve names for your internal AD.  You should add a forwarder to your Active Directory DNS server(s).

[image: DNS Forwarders]